# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context two db Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the follwoing controller which I have built two Linq queries in to merge into one to populate a drop down list. I have done this because data is coming from two different contexts.

The method is:

```
    private PeopleContext Peopledb = new PeopleContext();
    private IARContext db = new IARContext();        

    public ViewResult CreateAsset()
        {
        var Posts = (from a in Peopledb.Posts
                     orderby a.PostName
                     where a.Dormant == false
                     select new { a.PostId, a.PostName }).ToArray();

        var owners = from c in db.Owners
                     join a in Posts on c.PostId equals a.PostId
                     select new OwnerPost { OwnerId = c.OwnerId, PostName = a.PostName };

        CreateAssetViewModel viewModel = new CreateAssetViewModel
        {
            Asset = new Asset(),               
            Owners = owners.ToList(),
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The viewmodel is:

```
public class CreateAssetViewModel
    {
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    public Asset Asset { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OwnerPost> Owners { get; set; }

    }
```

I get the following error on the CreateAssetViewModel viewModel = new CreateAssetViewmodel section

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Owner Class:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool Dormant { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    public People.Models.Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Post Class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string PostName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool Dormant { get; set; }

    [StringLength(350)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

OwnerPost Class:

```
public class OwnerPost
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public string PostName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us the Owner class

Comment: @disklosr edited to add the classes

Comment: This has been answered now.

Comment: @disklosr I'm afraid not, I'm still at a loss as to how to get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end by adjusting the code to the following:

Viewmodel:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<OwnerPost> Owners { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult CreateAsset()
    {
        var posts = new List<People.Models.Post>(Peopledb.Posts);

        var owners = new List<Owner>(db.Owners);

        var ownerposts = from c in posts
                         join d in owners on c.PostId equals d.PostId
                         select new OwnerPost { OwnerId = d.OwnerId, PostName = c.PostName };

        CreateAssetViewModel viewModel = new CreateAssetViewModel
        {
            Asset = new Asset(),
            Owners = ownerposts.ToList(),
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following line of code:

```
Owners = owners.ToList();
```

Here you call to `List`, on a sequence of objects of anonymous type with two properties.

While the type of `Owners` is `IEnumerable<Owner>`. That being said, if you refactor a bit your linq query, you will get that you want.

```
 var owners = from c in db.Owners
              join a in Posts on c.PostId equals a.PostId
              select new Owner { PostId = c.PostId, PostName = a.PostName };
```

I **supposed** that the `Owner` has two properties, `PostId` and `PostName`. It could have more properties, but it should have at least those two.

Now your query returns an `IEnumerable<Owner>`, which is the expected type.

Comment: You had "select new {}" which is an anonymous class, in Christos answer he is specify the correct class "select new Owner"

Comment: I dont have a definition in Owner for PostName as I'm picking that up from Post in another db

Comment: The issue is clear, the type of `Owners` is `IEnumerable<Owner>`. So your query must return this. If it doesn't, then you can't assign it to the property called `Owners`. So you should project each element of your linq query to an `Owner` object. This is done by the `select new Owner`. However, I don't get what you mean by saying that you don't have a definition for `PostName`. If I am not wrong, you populate it in your query.

Comment: Changing my code to your refactored version gives me the following error : 'IAR.Models.Owner' does not contain a definition for 'PostName' 
 @Christos

Comment: You should be able to omit the PostId and PostName.  I believe that they are redundant.   Please verify.

Comment: @wayne.blackmon I need both PostId and PostName to populate a drop drown list so I dont belive I can omit them?

Comment: @PhillSanders well the output of the query is not an Owner object because some properties don't match. So you either add missing properties to Owner class, or you change the query to return an actual Owner class depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @disklosr I'm trying to get the data to poulate a drop down list, the OwnerId stored in the Owners Table in one db and the PostName linked via the key PostId from the Posts table in another db

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a strong type that has a property of an anonymous type. Change your `owners` query to return a collection of `Owner` objects or create a separate strong type that contains just the properties you want.

> I'm getting the exception "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

The reason is because you're trying to inject an in-memory query (`Posts`) into your EF query.  Since you don't use `Posts` you can just merge the queries:

```
    var owners = from c in db.Owners
                 join a in Peopledb.Post
                     on c.PostId equals a.PostId
                 where a.Dormant == false
                 select new OwnerPost { OwnerId = c.OwnerId, PostName = a.PostName };
```

Comment: Ive created a OwnerPost class with just PostId and PostName properties then changed my type in the query and viewmodel top OwnerPost but get this error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Update your question with the current queries and indicate where the error is thrown.